# TypeError: client.channels.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a channel if the channel name doesn't exist and I'm getting an error.

Code:

```js
const newchannel = client.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "channel-name");
if (!newchannel) {
    client.channels.create("new-channel", { type: "text" });
}
channel.send("");
```

Discord.js Version `^12.5.3`

Node Version `v12.18.3`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, `client.channels.create` is not a function. If you want to create a [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) in a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) you'll have to get the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) (from cache or by fetching it) and use [`GuildChannelManager#create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

---

```js
const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID");

const Channel = Guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "channel-name");

if (!Channel) {
    Guild.channels.create("channel-name", { type: "text" });
};
```

Comment: Im trying to send a message to every default channel the bot is currently in. would that be possible

Comment: Yes. You'll have to loop through every Guild (`client.guilds`), get the default channel for each Guild and send the message.